# Accessing a Model from ConfigServiceProvider not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to get all database values from the Configs database table into the ConfigServiceProvider, to reuse those variables in all blades throughout the site. But I keep on getting an error "Call to a member function connection() on null". Can it be that I cannot do database queries from a provider?

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Config;

class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $globals = Config::all();
        print_r($globals);
    }

}
```

If so, how do I do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in the 'register' method. Move it to the 'boot' method.

Specifically, you should only perform bindings in the register method, see the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers#the-register-method) for an in depth explanation.

Comment: In the same ConfigServiceProvider?